# How to determine if an array index is even?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am working on an assignment in which I must fill a **two dimensional array** row by row. If the row's index value is **even** (0, 2, 4, etc..) the row must fill from **right to left**. If the row's index value is **uneven** (1, 3, 5, etc...), then it must fill from **left to right**. What condition should I put in my if statement in order for the filling of rows to alternate in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: i%2==0 will check that

Comment: Or `if (index & 1) { /* It's odd */ }`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the modulo or remainder operation. Suppose **i** is an uneven number, therefore **i%2** will evaluate to **1**. For even numbers **i%2** will result in **0**.  As pointed out in the comment, use the condition 
`if (row_index % 2 == 0) {*do right to left thing*} else {do right to left thing}`.

Answer (score 2):

As the user with the weird name that i have no idea how to reference (sorry, feel free to edit your name in here) pointed out, i%2==0 should solve the problem.

The % (modulo) operator returns the remainder of the integer division, so if the row number is even you can divide it by 2 and have no remainder (i%2==0)

```
int[][] toBeFilled = new int[width][height];
for(int i=0;i<width;i++) {
    if(i%2==0)
        //Fill toBeFilled[i] from Right to Left
    else
        //Fill toBeFilled[i] from from Left to Right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code sample that may help. Note that this is C# (I'm not sitting in front of a Java compiler right now) so there are some very minor syntax differences but it should still be pretty readable.

```
    private static int[][] BuildArrays()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        // Whatever size you want
        int[][] array = new int[random.Next(1, 100)][];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            // Make an array of whatever size you want
            array[i] = new int[random.Next(1, 50)];

            // % is the modulo operator
            // Basically, this means "remainder when the index is divided by 2"
            // By definition, even numbers are evenly divisible by 2 and odd numbers aren't
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                // Even - we fill right to left
                for (int j = array[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    // Enter whatever you want
                    array[i][j] = random.Next();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Odd - we fill left to right
                for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    array[i][j] = random.Next();
                }
            }
        }

        return array;
    }
```